# Java String class interning

Tags: java, string

When i invoke

```
System.out.println("print this line here");
```

is the String

```
"print this line here"
```

interned?

The class **String** has a native interning mechanism to look up every new **String** value (except for those instantiated by the explicit call of its constructor) in a pool of values, and create a **String** object of that value only if it doesn't find it in this pool.

I'm wondering how this works with **String** constants. So, every time i'm invoking this statement in a loop, is "*print this line here*" being interned-- looked up in the pool to see whether it's there ... ?

//======================

NOTE: this is similar to but different than my prev.Q here.

Comment: Since `String` objects are immutable, all strings are constants.

Comment: You just keep repeating what the docs say. What's the point?

Comment: @PM77-1: Constant, but not necessarily interned; `"foo" != new String("foo")`.

Comment: @RussellZahniser - Yes, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals in code are compiled as part of the constant pool of the class. When the class file is first loaded, they are added to the String intern pool. By the time the statement is executed, it is just loading the interned string from the computed constant address.

**Edit:**

If you do what you suggest:

```
String str = new String ("print this line here");
```

... then you still have an interned constant string, plus a new string that is not == to the interned one.

Comment: just to beb clear-- it's not interning each & every time during execution(?)

Comment: No, it interns once when the class is loaded. The instruction that uses the string is just a load from a fixed address.

Comment: correct-- for the edit part btw. made a mistake in ref.to something else on quick-edit up there. removing it.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant chapter in the Java Language Specification is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). It states

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned"
>   so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

So, yes, the `String` literal `"print this line here"` is interned.

> I'm wondering how this works with String constants. So, every time i'm
>   invoking this statement in a loop, is "print this line here" being
>   interned-- looked up in the pool to see whether it's there ... ?

Not exactly, byte code is a little different. What you will see is the specific reference to a `String` object in the class' constant pool be pushed on the stack.

You can see this in the byte code

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;    Code:
      0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      3: ldc           #3                  // String print this line here
      5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      8: return
```

where the `ldc` [instruction is used to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

> push a constant #index from a constant pool (String, int or float)
>   onto the stack

That constant is used in the `println()` method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

`String` literals are compile time constants and are default interned.